# Making an array of object which have an asynchronous constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, asynchronous, callback

I want to do the following with NodeJS. Make an object array of the following, where each object has different local variables where they want to get when they initialize.

**obj.js**

```
var Obj = function (_id) {
    this.id = _id;
    var that=this;
    db.getData(_id,function(collection){ //this method is asynchronous 

        collection.toArray(function(err, items) {
            that.data=items;
        });
    });
}

Obj.prototype.data = [];  

module.exports = Obj;
```

**app.js**

```
var arr=[];
arr.push(new obj(24));
arr.push(new obj(41));
arr.push(new obj(24));
arr.push(new obj(42));
//then do tasks with the arr
```

But since the arr constructor is synchronous they may not have get all the data when I do calculations with the arr. So how to handle this scenario ? I want to make sure that all the objects are successfully created before doing any work with them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doing async work in a constructor is really awkward, why not move that work to a prototype function? Also on an unrelated note, why are you making a shared array `data`? It seems like you're using `data` as a per-instance variable instead of one that's shared amongst all `Obj` instances.

Comment: @mscdex data is different from each object :) I can move the asynchronous work to another prototype method. So how can I be sure that the async work is done ? :)

Comment: Set a flag on the instance that then you check in your other prototype functions that rely on `data`. Also, to make `data` a per-instance variable you can remove `Obj.prototype.data = [];` and just add `this.data = [];` right inside your constructor. Or maybe you can use that as your flag -- initially set `this.data = undefined;` then in your prototype functions do something like: `if (!this.data) throw new Error('No data');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

guy, what @mscdex said is correct.
Firstly, in your code, `data` will be shared in memory, you should use `this.data=[]` in constructor.
Secondly, as @mscdex said, move your method into prototype, say

```
Obj.prototype.load=function(){
    //code here...
}
```

then your code my like below:

```
var Obj = function(_id){
    this.id=_id;
    this.data = [];
}
Obj.prototype.load = function(){
    var that = this;
    db.getData(this.id,function(collection){ //this method is asynchronous
        collection.toArray(function(err, items) {
            that.data=items;
        });
    });
    return that;
}
```

finally, your question, how do you know all of them are ready.

```
Obj.prototype.ready = [];
Obj.prototype.loaded=function(){
    this.ready.push(1);
    if(this.ready.length == Obj.target)
        Obj.onComplete();
}
Obj.notifyme = function(callback,len){
    Obj.target = len;
    Obj.onComplete = callback;
}
```

the above code set an array to count load complete instances(use array because basic value could not be read from an instance's `__proto__` reference). So what you should do is add this event(function) to `load`, so the code at last may be as following:

```
Obj.prototype.load = function(){
    var that = this;
    db.getData(this.id,function(collection){ //this method is asynchronous
        collection.toArray(function(err, items) {
            that.data=items;
            that.loaded();
        });
    });
    return that;
}
var args = [24,41,42];
Obj.notifyme(function(){/*then do tasks with the arr*/},args.length);
var arr = args.map(function(arg){
    return new Obj(arg).load();
});
```

tell function `notifyme` the callback work and the number of instances. The last problem is if you do this routine more than one times you should reset `target` and `callback` since they are `Obj` global things.

Answer (score 1):

I would make use of Promise pattern. Here is prototype of such an approach. I used native browser Promise for implementation and testing. In case of NodeJS you can use Kowal's Q implementation with similar (or very close) API.

```
var Obj = function (_id) {
    this.id = _id;
    var that = this;

    this.promise = function() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve) {
            db.getData(_id, function (collection) {
                collection.toArray(function (err, items) {
                    that.data.push(items);
                    resolve(that);
                });
            });
        });
    }();
};

Obj.prototype.data = [];


function objFactory(args) {
    var promises = args.map(function(el) {
        return new Obj(el).promise;
    });
    return Promise.all(promises);
}

objFactory([24, 25, 41, 42]).then(function(arr) {
    console.log(arr, arr[0].data);
});
```

The idea is that when the promise object returned by `objFactory` resolves it will invoke corresponding `then` callback, inside of which it's reliable to work with `data` since it's populated for sure by that time.

Here is browser [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lopjjd2h/) I was testing code with. You will have to adopt it for NodeJS environment. But the idea remains the same.

For example using Kris Kowal's Q it will be something like this:

```
this.promise = function() {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    db.getData(_id, function (collection) {
        collection.toArray(function (err, items) {
            that.data.push(items);
            deferred.resolve(that);
        });
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}();
```

and `Q.all` instead of `Promise.all`.